# Combine multiple rows in one GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table `games` with information about computer games. One aspect is the region where the game was released. Some games have been released in multiple regions, that's why there are three regional columns: `region1`, `region2`, `region3`.

I would like to GROUP a selection of games in that way that - no matter in which of those three regions columns the same region is placed - I will end up with one list of distinct regions.

Very basic example of the table in question:

```
id | name_of_game | region1 | region2 | region3 
-----------------------------------------------
1    Phoenix        us        fr        de
2    Scramble       fr        uk
3    Defender       ru
```

I want to get the following output

```
region
-------
us
fr
de
uk
ru
```

I struggle to come up with a solution.

Comment: Oh, the pain of denormalised schema.  Consider normalising (i.e. splitting the region data into a separate table of `(game_id, region)` pairs)?

Comment: I'm with eggy. Normalisation is the way forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `union` for this

```
select region1 as region from table
union 
select region2 as region from table
union 
select region3 as region from table
```

To get the count of games for each region you can use following

```
select region,count(*)
from(
  select region1 as region,name_of_game from demo where region1 is not null
  union 
  select region2 as region,name_of_game from demo where region2 is not null
  union 
  select region3 as region,name_of_game from demo where region3 is not null
) t
group by region
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8ec22/4)

Comment: That, errr, was … easy! I never used union before, so this was pretty enlighting. Thanks. Would there be any chance that I can do a count on the distinct regions within that query?

Comment: @ArminHierstetter Count of games ?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: Oh, sorry, yes. Counting the games for all of the distinct regions ...

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: Again, I am overwhelmed by the knowledge people give for free. I have to think a bit about your solution because I am not savy enough to understand why it works … Thanks so much!